# What are the risks of using non exposed type in the public headers

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, pimpl-idiom

I am developing a library where one of its public interface class defined as:

```
class speed:
public:
    //constructors, operators, setter, getters...
private:
    float x,y,z; 
};
```

I think here that I am re-inventing the wheel again. Using something like `Eigen::vector3f` (or any other alternative from another known 3rd libraries)  instead of plain `float x,y,z` as a private member variable is much superior than re-writing all arithmetics operators taking care of all corners case.

In the same time, I do not want to expose any 3rd party with my library (that is a requirement that I have to meet).

Would it be wise to forward declare the the `Eigen::vector3f` or any other well-designed float vector and use it inside a suitable smart pointer?

To not trap in the opinion-based question style:

- **Is there any possible risk by using this approach?**
- **Would it, theoretically, decrease the performance since the data is dynamically allocated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a software engineering issue, and hence, the answer(s) are most likely to be based on opinion.

My suggestion:

Provide a function that returns a `Eigen::vector3f` given a `speed` object. Whether that function is a member function or a non-member function is secondary, though a non-member function is preferable.

Given that, whether you store the internal data using three `float`s or a `Eigen::vector3f` is immaterial.

> Is there any possible risk by using this approach?

I don't see any. However, I haven't used `Eigen::vector3f` in any project. I may be off target with my risk assessment.

> Would it, theoretically, decrease the performance since the data is dynamically allocated?

I don't see why it would. If you are going to dynamically allocate `speed` objects, the cost of such allocations would be independent of whether you store three `float`s or a `Eigen::vector3f` as member variable(s).

Answer (score 1):

You are weighing the cost of reinventing the wheel with somewhat heavy machinery (`Eigen::vector3f`) and increased maintenance effort (implementing the pimpl idiom). If your application does not care about the underlying machinery, i.e `Eigen::vector3f` can be swapped with `Boost.Units` or some other specialized library, then the pimpl idiom may be appropriate. This is even more true if you have a closed source application that needs to comply with the licenses of OSI-licensed projects, like Qt. The advantage is that if you ever need to switch in the future due to legal reasons or because the project no longer usable/dead, the pimpl idiom eases that.

As for performance degradation, you *possibly* will get increased memory usage/allocations/hinder the ability for the compiler to optimize. But these are hypothetical. Like any other situation, the only way to know is to measure/benchmark. I find it far more likely that an application dealing with physics is going to have bottlenecks in other areas.